# Can't figure out how to get time attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble using the `ImportXML()` function in Google spreadsheets. I would like to retrieve the time of posting on several [Reddit posts in a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgLkBqMZYl2FdDJ6dFJhUmZWUHVoNVdzRUprOEZRM3c), but I'm only having luck getting 28 Apr 2012, instead of 2012-04-28T02:19:06.348481+00:00, which is what I would like.

For example, [on this web page](http://www.reddit.com/r/BuyItForLife/comments/sw9m5/choosing_the_right_kitchen_knife_alton_brown/), I look in the source and see the following:

```
<div class='spacer'><div class="linkinfo">
    <div class="date">
        <span>this post was submitted on &#32;</span>
            <time datetime="2012-04-28T02:19:06.348481+00:00">28 Apr 2012</time>
    </div>
<div class="score">
```

However, this is the only line I can get to do anything:

```
=ImportXML(
"http://www.reddit.com/r/BuyItForLife/comments/jtjuz/bi4l_mission_statement_rules_etc/",
"//div[@class='date']")
```

Any suggestions? I've been searching and trying and searching and trying, and nothing is working.

Comment: Are you asking for an XPath expression or for something else?

Comment: An XPath expression, I suppose. Whatever would work in the Google Spreadsheets ImportXML() function.

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTXML requires that the document follow the XML/XHTML to work correctly. Looks that the document doesn't comply with this, so, instead of IMPORTXML use IMPORTDATA and then use QUERY and REGEXEXTRACT.

Example:

A1: Add the URL   `http://www.reddit.com/r/BuyItForLife/comments/jtjuz/bi4l_mission_statement_rules_etc/`
A2: Add the following formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(transpose(QUERY(importdata(A1),,1E+100)),,1E+100),
"datetime=""(.*?)""")
```

Result: `2011-08-25T01:32:23+00:00`

Explanation about the use of QUERY:

IMPORTDATA returns a 2D array. QUERY is used two times to concatenate the content of the array, the first time to put together all the rows, the second time to do the same for all the columns.

CONCATENATE and JOIN cannot be used because they have a 50000 character limit.

Answer (score -3):

You asked tough question and probably reached limits of google spreadsheets - usually you can check validity of Xpath attribute, for example for:

```
//*[@datetime="2011-08-25T01:45:37+00:00"]
```

result in answer cell must be

```
TRUE
```

see in sandbox row 21 sample with:

```
//div/@class="md"   TRUE
```

Comment: this provides answer (as showed in sandbox) that all known methods not helps