# Valid XPath does not return value for the IMPORTXML formula

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I don't understand how to get an attribute?

This code return error **error: The xPath query did not return any data**

```
=IMPORTXML(
  "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=01.01.2013&date_req2=15.03.2013&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235";
  "/ValCurs/Record/@Date"
)
```

There is a similar problem [Can't figure out how to get time attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378453/google-spreadsheet-importxml-cant-figure-out-how-to-get-time-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Must use the attribute name in lower case

```
=ImportXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=01.01.2013&date_req2=15.03.2013&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235";"/ValCurs/Record/@date")
```

Comment: Bless you for this answer.