# Import time in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having trouble to find the right formula to import dates from news websites into Google Sheet.

We have more than 300 website to retrieve the date from it, so I can't do it one by one.

I tried these formulas (the F column is my URL)

```
=IMPORTXML(F2;"//@class=pubdate")

=IMPORTXML(F3;"//date")
```

And then I saw this questions, but cannot understand where I fail to achieve what I want:

[Can't figure out how to get time attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378453/cant-figure-out-how-to-get-time-attribute)

And it says I have to use this formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(transpose(QUERY(importdata(F4),,1E+100)),,1E+100),"datetime=""(.*?)""")
```

So in the end, what I would like is:

```
[Column A : Title; B : text; C : Image; D : Tag ; F : URL; G : Date the publication was published][1]
```

Comment: What's the website?

Comment: Hello,
sorry for the late reply,

Comment: There're multiple news website : lesoir.be, lavenir.be, franceinfo... it isn't just one source